# Triggering wp_update_plugins cron to automatically update plugins in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to force plugin updates with WordPress, but it doesn't seem to be working. I need to force these updates within a custom plugin itself.

I added the following filter into my plugin:

`add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );`

I made sure that nothing in the wp_config file disallows auto-updates. Even though I didn't need to, to be safe I also set:

`define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );`
and `define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );`

I then installed the Advanced Cron Manager plugin to trigger the `wp_update_plugins` event, but this did not update any plugins.

I decided to simply call the `wp_maybe_auto_update()` function within my plugin on init... and it worked and updated my plugin - but also disabled it!

I am wondering if anyone knows why running the `wp_update_plugins` cron event wouldn't be updating any plugins? There must be a really simple solution here that I'm missing! Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following function to update a plugin programatically:

```
function upgrade_plugin( $plugin_slug ) {
  include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php';
  include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
  wp_cache_flush();
   
  $upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader();
  $upgraded = $upgrader->upgrade( $plugin_slug );
 
  return $upgraded;
}
```

& you could use that in conjunction with `get_plugins`

```
// Check if get_plugins() function exists. This is required on the front end of the
// site, since it is in a file that is normally only loaded in the admin.
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_plugins' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}

$all_plugins = get_plugins();
```

and then loop over it to update the plugins

```
foreach ( $all_plugins as $key => $value ) {
    upgrade_plugin( $key );
}
```

I found this article useful when putting together this answer: https://wpreset.com/programmatically-automatically-download-install-activate-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The code seems to be throwing back an error unfortunately: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function show_message() in ~/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php:161

I Googled this error and came back with nothing, unfortunately. I traced the show_message function and commented it out, which did run the code but nothing updated. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer to include `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php` let's see how that goes

Comment: Thanks! It still didn't work, but I took your idea and started including all files that were being referenced, which ended up being 6 files. This actually did work, but just like calling the wp_maybe_auto_update(), it disabled the plugin after the update.

Comment: I feel like this could all be done more cleanly using [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/) ... We're you able to find any success using `activate_plugin`? The article I linked mentions it.

Comment: Hi, this answer helps me a lot, this is the files I used: `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`
`wp-admin/includes/file.php`,
`wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php`,
`wp-admin/includes/class-plugin-upgrader.php`,
`wp-admin/includes/class-automatic-upgrader-skin.php`

Answer (score 0):

From the answer above I got this to work, you just need to remove the extra / from include_once ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php';
to make it: include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader-skin.php';

Answer (score 0):

When I am relying on a **cron event (Testing with WP Crontrol plugin) to take care of plugin update**, following code seems to be **working** with given required files:

```
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php';
include_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/misc.php';
$upgrader = new Plugin_Upgrader();
$result = $upgrader->upgrade($plugin_slug);
if (is_wp_error($result) || !$result) {
    // Check if error, else updated successfully
}
```